# A basis is a subset of the topology it generates

Tags: general-topology

I know this question is very basic but I just wanted to be sure. I'm reading through Munkres' Toplogy book, and he mentions that given a topology $\tau$ generated by some basis $\mathcal{B}$, each basis element is an element of the toplogy $\tau$. I just wanted to make sure I could prove this.

I need to show that given some $B \in \mathcal{B}$ and some $x \in B$, there exists some $B' \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B' \subset B$.

I want to use the definition of a basis: given any $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$ where $B_1,B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$, there exists some $B_3 \subset B_1 \cap B_2$ such that $x \in B_3$. In this case, I set $B_1=B_2=B$, and $B'=B_3$. But I'm not sure if this is legal, because the $B_1,B_2$ in this definition may have to be distinct. Munkres' definition used the word "two", but not distinct, which is where I'm unclear.

I'm also not sure if I'm allowed to set $B'=B$, or if I need to find some $B'$ *strictly* contained in $B$.

Thanks!

Comment: You are allowed to set $B'=B$

Answer (score 3):

Actually, what you have to prove is that $B\in\mathcal B\implies B\in\tau$. But $\tau$ is the set of all unions of elements of $\mathcal B$. So, in particular, $B\in\tau$.

Answer (score 2):

Recall, if $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for a topology, and $\tau$ is the topology generated by $\mathcal{B}$, a set $U \subset X$ is called open if for any $x \in X$ there is $x \in B$, $B \in \mathcal{B}$, $B \subset U$.

Then, to show $B \in \mathcal{B}$ is open, just note that for all $x \in B$, $B \subset B$, and by definition $B \in \mathcal{B}$.

Comment: Got it, the definition in the book used $\subset$ instead of $\subseteq$ so I wasn't sure if I could say $B \subset B$. Thanks!